# ReactJS - Elegant solution to toggle show element with ref

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, toggle, ref

If this.state.editMode is false then the input doesn't show, in which case the ref setup for this.textInput is undefined until the input shows.  However if I want to click on the span to show the input I need to focus on the input.

Does anybody have an elegant solution for this or am I overthinking?  Thank you in advance.

```
focusOnTextInput() {
    this.textInput.focus();
}

setEditMode() {
   this.editMode = !this.editMode;

   this.setState(() => ({
      editMode: this.editMode
   }));

   if (this.editMode) {
      this.focusOnTextInput();
   }
}


render() {
    return (
      <li className="task">
        {
          this.state.editMode ?
          <input
            type="text"
            ref={(input) => { this.textInput = input; }}
            onKeyUp={this.keyUpCheck}
            onChange={this.changeValue}
            value={this.state.newTitle} /> :
          <span onClick={this.setEditMode}>{ this.state.title }</span>
        }
        <span>{ this.props.done }</span>
        <span>{ this.props.inProgress }</span>
        <button onClick={this.props.onRemove}>X</button>
      </li>
    )
  }
```

Okay I added the change regarding the editMode which works perfectly and also the focus now works as ref means something... EXCELLENT, thank you Tony :-)

```
setEditMode() {
  this.setState(() => ({
    editMode: !this.state.editMode
  }));
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (this.state.editMode) {
    this.focusOnTextInput();
  }
}
```

Now how do I set this as complete and give you full marks..?

Comment: have you tried the `componentDidUpdate()` lifecycle? It seems like you could move your check for `editMode` and call to `focusOnTextInput()` to there

Comment: also I don't think you need `editMode` on both component state and a class property

Comment: Yeah the issue I had with editmode as a state was when I set it to !this.state.editMode it wasn't instantly changing it. :-S  But I'll have a look at componentDidUpdate a little later tonight, sounds like an interesting plan.

Comment: yeah, `setState()` is asynchronous; that's why you should be able to use `componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState)` and see that `this.state.editMode` is now set

Comment: Unfortunately "Mark Rotteveel", "duggu", "Dmitry", "Olesandr" there is no bloody Answer to accept on here if you actually looked at this properly you would have seen.  Fix the site, allow a comment to be made an answer!  Who are you lot the bloody Spanish Inquisition.

Comment: I put my comment in and answer so you can accept it @Pocketninja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState)` you will be able to check if `this.state.editMode` is now set and call your `this.focusOnTextInput()`